# How to awk print a subtring and trim trailing and ending white space of the same subtring in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Hello guys I'm trying parse xinput stdout to find the right device to disable the keyboard. So this is the code that I have but it looks sloppy and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it.

```
xinput -list --short | grep -E "keyboard.*slave" | awk 'NR==1{print substr($0,7,41)}' | awk '{$1=$1}1'
```

I do not know how long the substring needs to be so I include 41 as the index to encompass the maximum length of the potential device names. This results in a white space at the end that needs to be trimmed so I pass it through another awk pipe. I would like to know if the last 2 awk calls can be condensed into 1

Comment: learn to chain your `awk` statments together with the `;` char. I would expect `awk ...7,41);$1=$1;print}` to work. You can also skip the `egrep` by matching like `awk '/keyboard.*slave/{print sub...` . Good luck.

Comment: Put a sample  `xinput -list --short` output and show what you want to trim from there..

Comment: Do you have more than one keyboard attached in your PC? There are other more comfortable ways to find and disable the keyboard....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to substitute the white space away, and `awk` can [do the pattern match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html#Very-Simple) for you, too:

```
xinput -list --short | awk '
    /keyboard.*slave/ { 
        s = substr($0, 7, 41);
        sub(/ *$/, "", s);
        print s;
        exit;
   }'
```

That would stop after the first matching line, which I suppose you wanted, since the original only acted on the first record read by `awk`.

So,

```
$ cat keyb
mouse mouse something
keyboard slave foo
keyboard slave bar
$ awk '/keyboard.*slave/ {  s = substr($0, 7, 41); sub(/ *$/, "", s); print s; exit; }'  < keyb
rd slave foo
```

Comment: Yes but how do you only print out the first line? you forgot to add that part

Comment: @B.Bagry, there's the `exit` to stop the awk script at the end of the block at the first matching line. Testing `NR==1` wouldn't be right here, since without the preceding `grep`, the `awk` script sees the whole input file, even the non-matching lines.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot to include the exit. Thanks so much

Comment: I tried to reuse this elsewhere and `sub(/ +/, "", $1)` worked for me but `sub(/ *$/, "", $1)` would not (it printed a 1 which leads me to think that awk was using the literal “ $1” as the input).

I prefer / +/ as the regex ensures that you only do the substitution if there is at least one space. / */ will always do the substitution as anything matches “ *” zero or more times).

Comment: @JackChidley, mmh, I can't follow exactly what it is you were doing, can you show a short but complete command? Like what's the input and the exact output? `printf 'foo   :asdf' | awk -F: -v OFS=: '{ sub(/ *$/, "", $1) } 1 '` prints `foo:asdf`, removing the trailing spaces from the first field

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to disable your keyboard you can use xinput directly.

The output of xinput is like this:

```
$ xinput list
Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard             id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                            id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                               id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The keyboard description i.e `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` is always the same. What is different is the id=10 (different id can be assigned by the system across reboots).

As a result you can get the id of your keyboard like

```
$ xinput list --id-only "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" 
10
```

And you can then disable your keyboard like

```
$ kid=$(xinput list --id-only "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard")
$ xinput disable "$kid"   #use xinput enable to enable it.
```

Or even you can use device description directly with xinput disable:

```
$ xinput disable "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
```

As a result , since device description is always the same , you don't need any kind of text processing to identify and disable your keyboard.

Comment: I know this, however, Im writing a script that will work also on a desktop keyboard. So i dont think that AT translated Set 2 keyboard would work, as this is exactly how i had it before in my code